Multiple Interfaces for the same object
I try to use a different type of declaration for my object "docs", because I want to use the same interface ResponseInterface for different requests, one is for User[] and other is for Hospitals[] or whatever.
The thing is that I want to use the same declarations of baseResponseInterface in HospitalInterface & UserInterface sharing the "docs" for the different request or type of elements.
I haven't achieved that.
I've followed some steps that I found with this:
In my response.interface.ts file:
export type ResponseInterface = UserInterface | HospitalInterface;

interface baseResponseInterface {
    totalPages: number,
    page: number,
    hasNextPage: boolean,
    hasPrevPage: boolean,
    nextPage: number | null,
    prevPage: number | null,
    limit: number,
    pagingCounter: number,
    totalDocs: number,
}

interface HospitalInterface extends baseResponseInterface{
    docs: HospitalInterfacee[]
}

interface UserInterface extends baseResponseInterface{
    docs: User[],
}

In my components.ts I declare my interface with this
public response: ResponseInterface | undefined;

but in the HTML code I get this error message:
<tr *ngFor="let user of response?.docs; let index = index">
...
</tr>


Could someone help me with this? Is it possible?
Or do I need to create my own interface for each type of response?
UserResponseInterface & HospitalResponseInterface?

Please don't repeat the same text over again. If the UX is asking you for more text, write more different text. (Like the text of the error message, which should be included as text, not as a picture of text).

Your issue is not with your interfaces. Your issue is with what you're trying to for loop over.

@HereticMonkey i'll edit my question. Thanks!

An idiomatic approach would be to use generic type parameters as shown here. If this meets your needs, I can write an answer explaining (or find a suitable duplicate target for this question). If not, what did I miss?

The reason you're getting this is because the for loop is expecting an array and response?.docs can be undefined.
<tr *ngFor="let user of (response?.docs ?? []); let index = index">


I try it, but i get the same error. do i need to change the initialization of the response in my component?

What's the error you're getting with this change?

src/app/pages/maintenance/users/users.component.html:54:50 - error TS2322: Type '_HospitalInterface[] | User[] | undefined' is not assignable to type '(_HospitalInterface[] & NgIterable<_HospitalInterface>) | null | undefined'.
54                             <tr *ngFor="let user of response?.docs; let index = index">
~~
src/app/pages/maintenance/users/users.component.ts:14:16
14   templateUrl: './users.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component UsersComponent

The same error like the image

Post the full file

use   "strictPropertyInitialization": false inside the tsconfig.json file as shown below, so you don`t need to initialize the instance property and you can remove undefined from the
public response: ResponseInterface;

this should resolve the error.
  "compilerOptions": {
  "strictPropertyInitialization": false,


I'm working with Angular v16.1, i'm not sure if this option is the correct, because i don't  have that option in my tsconfig.json, or i need to add that opcion on it?
